# Create file with contents from shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How do I, in a shell script, create a file called foo.conf and make it contain:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

# Default
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Use a "here document":

```
cat > foo.conf << EOF
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

# Default
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

Comment: @ams Can one have variables that get interpreted within the document?

Comment: Yes. How it's interpreted depends on what quotes you put around the `EOF`.

Comment: For those using it inside an indented code section, the text and the final EOF should not be indented and be at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Example of variable interpolation. Variable declaration earlier in file: `my_var="foo"`. Reference inside EOF heredoc: `$my_var` will resolve to `foo`.

Answer (score 34):

You can do that with `echo`:

```
echo 'NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

# Default
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost>' > foo.conf
```

Everything enclosed by single quotes are interpreted as literals, so you just write that block into a file called `foo.conf`. If it doesn't exist, it will be created. If it does exist, it will be overwritten.

Comment: This works, but is limited by the maximum command line length.

Comment: Also it only works as long as you don't have apostrophes in the document.

Answer (score 11):

a heredoc might be the simplest way:

```
cat <<END >foo.conf
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

# Default
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost>
END
```

Comment: Same as the accepted answer with the only difference that it shows that the `<<END` delimiter can come before the redirection `>foo.conf`. Which version one finds more readable is a matter of personal preference of course.

Answer (score 7):

This code fitted best for me:

```
sudo dd of=foo.conf << EOF
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost
</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

It was the only one I could use with `sudo` out of the box!